# How to update table with column set NULL in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, null

i have a problem with update column with set data to NULL, i have a table `user` with each one column is `id_parent` column, user can delete parent and can add parent, so if `user` have a `parent`, `id_parent` will set with user's `parent id` , but user can delete parent's data, so if `user` delete parent's data, `id_parent` column, will set to NULL. so how to set data to null in database not `" "` but `NULL`. 
here's my `user` table.

```
user

id_user | name | address | id_parent
```

Answer (score 6):

use this to set null column.it will work, dont forget add false on third parameter SET on active record

```
$this->db->set('id_parent', 'NULL', false);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can try this code in 'model', hope it'll work:

```
public function update_std_marks($id_user) {

    $this->db->set('id_parent', null);
    $this->db->where('id_user', $id_user);
    $this->db->update('user');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I was curious so I wanted to see how CodeIgniter's Active Record would handle different variations of syntax when working with a null value.  I'll map out several test cases for `where()` and `set()` method calls.

Battery of `where()` tests:

1. ```
   ->where('col', null)                  // `col` IS NULL
   ```
2. ```
   ->where('col', null, false)           // col IS NULL
   ```
3. ```
   ->where('col', 'NULL')                // `col` = 'NULL'
   ```
4. ```
   ->where('col', 'NULL', false)         // col =  NULL
   ```
5. ```
   ->where('col IS NULL')                // `col` IS NULL
   ```
6. ```
   ->where('col IS NULL', null)          // `col` IS NULL
   ```
7. ```
   ->where('col IS NULL', null, false)   // col IS NULL
   ```
8. ```
   ->where('col', 'IS NULL')             // `col` 'IS NULL'
   ```
9. ```
   ->where('col', 'IS NULL', false)      // col = IS NULL
   ```

Properly quoted and formed: #1, #5, #6 (**recommended**)
Logically formed, but not quoted: #2, #7 (**not recommended**)
Inappropriate rendered syntax: #3, #4, #8, #9 (**do not use**)

---

Battery of `set()` tests:

1. ```
   ->set('col', null)                  // `col` = NULL
   ```
2. ```
   ->set('col', null, false)           // col =
   ```
3. ```
   ->set('col', 'NULL')                // `col` = 'NULL'
   ```
4. ```
   ->set('col', 'NULL', false)         // col = NULL
   ```
5. ```
   ->set('col IS NULL')                // `col IS` `NULL` = ''
   ```
6. ```
   ->set('col IS NULL', null)          // `col IS` `NULL` = NULL
   ```
7. ```
   ->set('col IS NULL', null, false)   // col IS NULL =
   ```
8. ```
   ->set('col', 'IS NULL')             // `col` = 'IS NULL'
   ```
9. ```
   ->set('col', 'IS NULL', false)      // col = IS NULL
   ```

Properly quoted and formed: #1 (**recommended**)
Logically formed, but not quoted: #4 (**not recommended**)
Inappropriate rendered syntax: #2, #3, #5, #6, #7, #8, #9 (**do not use**)

Answer (score 2):

Your user table must have the attribute set to is_null in the `id_parent` field. Otherwise you can't.

The query should be something like

```
Update table user set id_parent = null where id_user = X
```

You can set that column nullable with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY id_parent int(11) null;
```

Try this for codeigniter:

```
$fields = array(
                        'id_parent' => array(
                                                         'name' => 'id_parent',
                                                         'type' => 'INT',
                                                ),
);
$this->dbforge->modify_column('user', $fields);
```

or simply:

```
$this->db->query('ALTER TABLE user MODIFY id_parent int(11) null;');
```

Comment: so i can user the alter table/? it's same with use active record in codeigniter?